# Bootstrap col-xs-* not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can someone help me figure out what's going on with my mobile version of my page? I'm modifying the dashboard example from getbootstrap.com. I want to modify the mobile version of one of the main rows to display as rows of three divs each.

```
              <div class="row placeholders">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 placeholder">
                        <div class="circleText">3</div>
                        <h4>Active Users</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Total Active Users</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 placeholder">
                        <div class="circleText">3</div>
                        <h4>Items</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Items in Database</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 placeholder">
                        <div class="circleText">3</div>
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 placeholder">
                        <div class="circleText">3</div>
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 placeholder">
                        <div class="circleText">3</div>
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 placeholder">
                        <div class="circleText">3</div>
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The `col-xs` is normally `col-xs-6` in the template, with a total of four columns, which adds to 24. So, when you view on mobile, it shows two in each row (since 24 gets split to two rows of 12).
The weird part is that I've changed it to be `col-xs-4` with a total of six columns, which I want to show on mobile as two rows of three. But when I view on mobile, the first row is 3, but the second row's first column gets pushed to a third row by itself. Why is this happening??

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly caused if one of the `col-sm-4` columns is of a different (larger) height than the others.
You can fix this by adding a `clearfix` div between the rows or by making sure the the three columns are of the same size (height-wise)

My personal suggestion is to do it through javascript. Calculate the maximum height of all columns and assign that height to all columns. But if you just want a css solution, you can consider setting the `max-height` for the columns